# Get all .py files created for 2 previous days

Tags: python

I want to get all `.py` files that were created for the 2 previous days.

I wrote code to search for files with the extension `.py`, and now I need to test their age. Here is the code I have so far:

```py
import os
import shutil
import getctime

source = r'/Users/sourcedir'
destination = r'/Users/destdir'

for root, dir, files in os.walk(source):
    for file in files:
        if '.py' in file:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), destination)
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: What specific problem do you have?

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ i need to specify which of '.py' were made for two previous days only

Comment: @MichaelButscher i need to specify which of '.py' were made for two previous days only

Comment: A more reliable way to test if the file name ends in `.py` is `if file.endswith('.py')`.

Comment: It is not clear for me. Using today as the reference, do you want to select files from, yesterday (today - 1), and the day before (today - 2), or anything older than 2 days ago (today - 2)? Also, are you going to consider just the day difference, or time should be considered as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to test each file in the directory for it's modification date. (Assuming you want files *modified* more than two days ago, creation is different than modification or accessing depending on your OS, to be clear on Windows this function returns *creation* date)

The `os.path.getmtime('file_path')` function returns the creation time (Windows) or last change time (Linux) of a file as an epochal timestamp.

You'll need to compare this epochal timestamp with your reference timestamp (two days ago?), and if older proceed with your `move(...)` call.

Answer (score 1):

To get the '.py' files created in 2 days, you can use the `Path` class from the `pathlib` module as an alternative for doing stuffs with filesystem paths.

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

SOURCE = Path("Path_to_Searchfor")
DESTINATION = Path("Path_to_Moveto")
SINCE = 2

# Time now
time_now = datetime.now()

# Iterating path for '.py' files
for file in SOURCE.rglob("*.py"):
    created_time = file.stat().st_ctime
    created_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(created_time)
    created_on = (time_now - created_time).days  # calculating days since file created

    # Moving file to destination only <=2 days
    if created_on <= SINCE:
        file.replace(DESTINATION.joinpath(file.name))
```

Using the `Path` class, gives more advantage for iterating over the given path using `glob` method with some pattern. The `rglob("*.py")` in the for statement does search for all the python files inside the source path and returns a iterable of Path object.

The `stat` method gives the properties of the '.py' file, using that calculating the  days created since by `datetime` module.

And the `replace` method of Path class replaces the `shutil.move` and moves the file to the passed in destination.

Comment: IMHO, `SOURCE.rglob("*.py"):` is more readable than `SOURCE.glob("**/*.py"):`.

Comment: Thank you for noticing @accdias, I updated `glob("**/*.py")`  with `rglob("*.py")`

Comment: Another thing that I prefer instead of `DESTINATION.joinpath(file.name)` is `DESTINATION / file.name`, which, also IMHO, is more readable.

Comment: Yeah @accdias, `DESTINATION / file.name` is more readable and pythonic, but for beginners `joinpath` method explicitly says what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
seconds_in_two_days = 2 * 24 * 60 * 60
two_days_ago = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() - seconds_in_two_days
if os.path.getctime(file) > two_days_ago:
   # ...
```

Other variations are possible if you wanted to include the whole day of two days ago.